# Start Gnome at lock screen at startup in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-gnome

When I first log into ubuntu the following screen comes -
[image: Unity lock screen]

I have ubuntu-gnome-desktop installed and I am able to select it on the unity lock screen. I want gnome start screen to come at start by default.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear but it sounds as you want to switch from lightdm to gdm. This should be doable using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`. This of course requires *gdm* to be installed.

Found a guide for 14.04 but it should work for 16.04 as well (https://itsfoss.com/switch-gdm-and-lightdm-in-ubuntu-14-04/)